# Puppeteer button not clicking

Tags: button, click, puppeteer

I can't seem to get a button to be clicked using puppeteer. Here is my code and below is as screenshot of the DOM. Note that I'm able to type the email just fine and the correct button element is selected but I can't get it to click it.

```
  const form = await page.$('[action="https://deadstock.us6.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=be9b719d1c345d54269781365&id=5534002567"]');
  const email = await form.$('#mce-EMAIL');
  const sub = await form.$('#mc-embedded-subscribe');
  await email.type(MyData[row].email);
  await sub.click;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you check the length of `$$('#mc-embedded-subscribe')` you can see there are more elements with the very same selector. So you need to select all of them first with `page.$$`, then you need to click on the 1st one, by selecting the index `[0]`. And you need to use [`elementHandle.click()`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.0.0&show=api-elementhandleclickoptions), your click was missing the parenthesis.

```js
  const sub = await form.$$('#mc-embedded-subscribe');
  ...
  await sub[0].click();
```